# gcf not giving same figure id as figure used to draw it

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
li = [[0,0],[20,10], [30,40] ]
xs = [x[0] for x in li]
ys = [x[1] for x in li]

aa = [0, 10, 40]
bb = [0, 10, 40]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
print "type(fig) : " , type(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
print "type(ax) : " , type(ax)
print "ax : " , ax

ax.plot(xs, ys, '--', linewidth=2, color='red')
ax.plot(ys, xs)
ax.plot(aa, bb)

plt.legend(('PID_1', 'PID_2'), loc='best', shadow=True, fancybox=True,  ncol=2)
plt.show()

gca = fig.gca() #could have used plt.gca() also
print "fig    : " , fig , ", type(fig)    : " , type(fig), ", id(fig) :    " , id(fig)

figObj = gca.get_figure()
print "figObj : " , figObj , ", type(figObj) : " , type(figObj) , ", id(figObj) : " , id(figObj)


currGcf = plt.gcf()
print "currGcf    : " , currGcf , ", type(currGcf)    : " , type(currGcf), ", id(currGcF) : " , id(currGcf)
```

Output:

```
fig    :  Figure(960x320) , type(fig)    :  <class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'> , id(fig) :     172216392
figObj :  Figure(960x320) , type(figObj) :  <class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'> , id(figObj) :  172216392
currGcf    :  Figure(480x320) , type(currGcf)    :  <class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'> , id(currGcF) :  213232048
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xcb5a9b0>
```

I thought that gcf gives the get current figure.. So, in this case, first two outputs give same id and size which is expected.

But, the last gcf output for size and id is different..
Please explain, why is this difference.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your placement of `plt.show()`. To get the script to run after you have called `show`, you need to close the window. This then changes the "current" figure (if you try plotting something else, it will appear on a new figure window).

If you instead move `plt.show()` to the end of your script, all three lines (`fig, figObj, currGcf`) will print the same object id